# Question with Divisibility proof

Tags: divisibility, proof-explanation

I have a simple proof question:

Suppose $a,b \in \Bbb Z$ where $a|b$. If $a|(b-c)$, then $a|c$.

I have solved it below, but is my way a valid answer? Is there a better clear way of proving this?

Suppose $a|(b-c)$ is true given $a|b$.

Then $\frac{b}{a} = k, k \in \Bbb Z. $ Re-arrange for b: $b = ka$

Then $\frac{b-c}{a} = \frac{ka-c}{a} = \frac{ka}{a}-\frac{c}{a}$

Since $\frac{b-c}{a} = \frac{ka}{a}-\frac{c}{a}$, it shows that a divides c, $a|c$

QED

Comment: In divisibility proofs, we try to avoid "fraction" notation. This is because there are number systems where divisibility makes sense but fractions do not, and you want to know how much of "divisibility" makes sense without fractions.

Comment: So, rather than writing $\frac{b}{a}=k$, for some $k$, we write $b=ak$ for some $k$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews so my answer above is not valid?

Comment: Depends on what you've already proven, really. Most number theory classes do not define or use $\frac{b}{a}$, initially, so, in those cases, your proof is invalid.

Comment: One reason not to use fraction notation: It is true that zero divides zero ( $0\mid 0$,) but $\frac{0}{0}$ is undefined. So you have to prove the case $a=0$ separately, even if you do have access to fractions. But the reason it is true for $a=0$ is the same as the reason it is true for non-zero $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a,b,c\in\mathbb Z$ and $a\mid b$ and $a\mid b-c$, then $b=ak$ and $b-c=am$ for some $k,m\in\Bbb Z$, so $c=b-am=ak-am=a(k-m)$, where $k-m\in\mathbb Z$, so $a\mid c$.